# How to get all selected values from multiple select option?

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact form with multiple select option. But there is only 1 value appear in the email after the contact form submitted. Would like to look for solution to get this work.

/*** My code begins ***/

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$contactperson = $_POST['contactperson'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$machinemodel = $_POST['machinemodel'];
$serialnumber = $_POST['serialnumber'];
$problems = $_POST['problems']; <--- this is multiple selection values
$inquiry = $_POST['inquiry'];
$security = $_POST['security'];
$from = "YT Copier";
$to = "mail@jornes.com";
$subject = "Admin, someone submitted service request form.";
$message = "Admin, someone has submitted service request form. Details are as follow: \n\nName: $title $contactperson\n\nPhone Number: $phonenumber\n\nEmail Address: $emailaddress\n\nCompany Name: $companyname\n\nMachine Brand:\n$brand\n\nMachine Model: $machinemodel\n\nSerial Number: $serialnumber\n\nProblem Facing: $problems\n\nMessage: $inquiry";

if ($security=="13") {
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
   header("Location:/supports/submit-service-request/?s=s");
}

else {
   header("Location:/supports/submit-service-request/?s=e");
}
```

<-- HTML Begins here -->

```
<select multiple="multiple" name='problems' id='problems' class="inpBox multiple" size='8' >
        <option value="Cannot Copy">Cannot Copy</option>
        <option value="Cannot Print">Cannot Print</option>
        <option value="Cannot Print">Cannot Scan</option>
        <option value="Cannot Fax">Cannot Fax</option>
        <option value="Lines Appear When Printing/Copying">Lines Appear When Printing/Copying</option>
        <option value="Scan to Email Failed">Scan to Email Failed</option>
        <option value="Toner Low/Empty">Toner Low/Empty</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

/*** Code Ends ***/

This is the php code in the file name "process.php" to process the form. The value of "$problems" is a multiple select option. I tried to select a few choices when filling out the form, but at the end, there is only 1 single value showing in the email. Can someone help? What code should i add to make it work?  Truly appreciate if someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use name as like `problems[]` instead of `problems`

```
//Simple Form and getting the values

<form name="s" method="post" action="" >
 <select multiple="multiple" name='problems[]' id='problems' class="inpBox multiple" size='50' style="height:150px;" >
        <option value="Cannot Copy">Cannot Copy</option>
        <option value="Cannot Print">Cannot Print</option>
        <option value="Cannot Print">Cannot Scan</option>
        <option value="Cannot Fax">Cannot Fax</option>
        <option value="Lines Appear When Printing/Copying">Lines Appear When Printing/Copying</option>
        <option value="Scan to Email Failed">Scan to Email Failed</option>
        <option value="Toner Low/Empty">Toner Low/Empty</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $problems =  implode(',', $_POST['problems']);
    echo $problems;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for fast response! I tried. It won't work. The value turns back with no value and "array" appears only after i used the name as "problems[]". Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Faizphp, thanks for your updated code. But it is still won't work. Can you show me how to place the php code in my php file? I tried, but it says an error when i submit the form. The message is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ytcopier/public_html/process_service_request.php on line 12

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ytcopier/public_html/process_service_request.php:12) in /home/ytcopier/public_html/process_service_request.php on line 24. Please advice! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Faizphp, i hereby attached the snapshot of php code in my process form file. See if i have placed your code wrongly, because it still doesn't work. Comes with single value only. And i put "[]" after the id named "problems", end up it returned with the word "Array" in email after the form submitted.
http://www.ytcopier.com.my/img/process-form-php-file.jpg